# Which of the following sets are dense in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Which of the following sets are dense in $C[0,1]$ with respect to sup-norm topology?

$1$. {$f$$\in$ $C[0,1]$ : $f$ is a polynomial }

$2$. {$f$$\in$ $C[0,1]$ :$f(0)$=$0$}

$3$. {$f$$\in$ $C[0,1]$ :$f(0)$$\neq$$0$}

$4$. {$f$$\in$$C[0,1]$ :$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$=$5}

I am thinking to apply Stone-weierstrass theorem but I don't know how to use it properly. Please help!

Comment: Stone-Weierstraß is a good idea for the first one. What does it exactly state? Any thoughts on 2.-4.?

Comment: @mathmax: From Stone weierstass says polynomials are dense in $C[0,1]$. I get the 1st one as my correct answer, as you said. But I'm having no hints for the rest. cann't it be done using Stone Weierstrass?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer: $1,\, 3$

Proof:

1. Stone-Weierstrass theorem states explicitly  the dense property of the polynomials in $(C[0,1],\parallel\cdot\parallel_\infty)$
2. It is not dense. Because it is a proper closed subset of  $(C[0,1],\parallel\cdot\parallel_\infty)$ as it is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under the continuous map $f\mapsto f(0)$.
3. It is dense. It is obvious that every element of that set is a limit point of that set. So now, let $f(0)=0$. Then the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f(x)+\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $f$ with respect to supnorm and $f_n(0)=\frac{1}{n}\neq 0$.
4. It is not dense. Because it is   the inverse of the set $\{5\}$ under the continuous map $f\mapsto \int_0^1 f(x)dx$. And hence it is a proper closed set.

Comment: For #2 one can also observe that any sufficiently small neighborhood of the constant function $f(x) = 42$ has empty intersection with the set under consideration. In fact, the 2nd example not only fails to be dense, but there are balls having arbitrarily large diameter that have empty intersection with the set.

Comment: @chellapillai; Can you please elaborate how the maps defined by you in options 2 and 4 are continuous?furthermore are these map open?

Comment: @Ibs Just notice that they are all linear maps. And continuity can be checked in the standard way.

Comment: @chellapilai If I am not wrong then showing boundedness is an easy task and you want me to prove the same,right?

Answer (score 4):

(1) follows directly from the stone-weirstrass theorem, since $[0,1]$ is a closed interval.

(2) is not dense, show that $f(x)=1$ is not a limit point

(3) Here, the closure of this set is $C[0,1]$, try showing that any $g\in C[0,1]$ with $g(0)=0$ is a limit point.

(4) Not dense, again show that $f(x)=1$ is not a limit point.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint for 2 :**

Let, $S=\{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)\not =0\}$.

Then $S=\{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)<0\}\cup \{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)>0\}$.

So, $\overline S=\{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)\le0\}\cup \{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)\ge0\}=C[0,1]$.

So, $S$ is dense in $C[0,1]$.

Again as $S$ is the union of two open sets so it is open subset of $C[0,1]$.

Hence its complement is nowhere dense.

That is, the set $\{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)=0\}$ is nowhere dense.

Similarly option 4 is nowhere dense.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

1. Stone-weierstrass theorem
2. Think about $\{x,x^2,x^3\cdots\}$
3. Think about $\{a+x^i : a\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}; i\in \mathbb{N}\}$
4. I have no hint for this as of now but i believe this is too small to generate $C[0,1]$

Comment: How to use your 2nd and 3rd hint? what do I need to show? @Praphulla Koushik

Comment: You need to spend some more time... what polynomials do you think are not in $2$??

Comment: The constant polynomials, right?

Comment: Yes... can you get constant function as limit function of elements in $2$??

Comment: and for the (3) rd? This is dense, right?

Comment: If you have accepted the other question you should know what does my hint for third condition says... those are not different...